# Reuse JWT between devices or create new tokens

Tags: jwt

This is an architectural  question related to the use of jwt.

When user logs in in my mobile app I generate a jwt. I do not know what strategy to follow when the same user logins on multiple mobile devices: to share the same jwt in all devices or to create a new jwt per device login?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new token for each login.

apart from security issues, just not practical. To reuse tokens will need to store them on the server. This eliminates one of the advantages of JW : no need server space . What happens when a token is about to expire ? you issue a new JWT ? otherwise you will not be synchronized devices